# how to create a new table from a previous one importing all the columns?

Tags: sas

I would like to create a new table and save it using a specific libname `'results'`. This table should contain all the variables generate from another table. I thought of using `proc sql`, but I do not know how to import all the fields of the table that I want to 'copy' into a new one. 
For example: the `table A` that I want create should have all the variables (including its values) of `table B`:

```
column1 column2 column3 ... 
1.........2........3
32........43.......54
....
```

and I want to save it as `rslt` using a specific libname called `'results'` (permanent tables, not temporary).

How could I do it?

Comment: Why do you need to create a copy? There might be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to assign a libname 'results'. Then sintax is: libname results "path";
After this, with proc sql you can create a new table you want.

```
proc sql;
    create table results.tableA as 
    select * from tableB;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard way to create a new table. Just make sure your library `Results` is created prior.

```
Data Results.New_Data;
    Set Old_table;
Run;
```